# Test metodo de modelo con Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, test, rspec

Estoy intentando realizar el test del metodo 'review_turn', que verifica si un turno ya existe en la base de datos o no. El metodo se encuentra en el modelo de 'Turns'. He intentado lo siguiente pero nose si es correcto:

Mi modelo tiene el siguiente metodo:

```
# Verifico que el turno este libre aún.
def self.review_turn(fecha, hs)
  Turn.where('date_turn = ? AND hs_turn = ? AND canceled = ?', fecha, hs, false)
end
```

Dentro de /spec/models/turn_spec.rb tengo lo siguiente:

```
# == Schema Information

# Table name: turns

#  id           :bigint           not null, primary key
#  date_turn    :date
#  hs_turn      :time
#  canceled     :boolean
#  provider_id  :bigint
#  affiliate_id :bigint
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Turn, type: :model do

  it { is_expected.to belong_to(:affiliate) }
  it { is_expected.to belong_to(:provider) }

  context 'Method spec review_turn' do
  it ' review_turn' do
    turn1 = create(:turn)
    turn2 = create(:turn)
    expect(turn2.review_turn).to eq(nil)
  end
  end

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `self.review_turn` pertenece a la clase, no a la instancia, por lo tanto deberías se llama desde la clase; tal como tienes definido ese método, la prueba debería ser así:

```
it 'review_turn' do
  turn1 = create(:turn)
  turn2 = create(:turn)

  expect(Turn.review_turn(turn2.date_turn, turn2.hs_turn)).to be_empty
end
```

- Utilizo `be_empty` ya que el método te regresará siempre una colección (vacía cuando no encuentre resultados).

Como mejora podrías refactorizar tu método para que reciba el objeto, en lugar de sus atributos; ejemplo:

```
def self.review_turn(turn)
  Turn.where(date_turn: turn.date_turn, hs_turn: turn.hr_turn, canceled: false)
end
```

Y la prueba cambiaría a:

```
it 'review_turn' do
  turn1 = create(:turn)
  turn2 = create(:turn)

  expect(Turn.review_turn(turn2)).to be_empty
end
```

Comment: Entiendo. Y para verificar que lo que recibo es vacio o nulo como seria? Deberia reemplazar el 'be_empty' por que cosa?

Comment: `be_empty` verifica justamente que la collección esté vacía.

Comment: Agregue el error que me arroja en el posteo, al realizar el test que me sugeriste, hay algo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: @francofernandez ¿cuá es el error?

Comment: Failure/Error: expect(Turn.review_turn(turn2.date_turn, turn2.hs_turn)).to be_empty
     expected `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Turn id: 2, date_turn: "2007-06-13", hs_turn: "2000-01-01 17:25:43", canc...der_id: 16, affiliate_id: 2, created_at: "2021-10-21 17:25:43", updated_at: "2021-10-21 17:25:43">]>.empty?` to be truthy, got false

Comment: @francofernandez Estás creando dos objectos `Turn` iguales, por lo tanto la consulta realizada en `review_turn` sí te regresa resultados. Si quieres probar que no esté vacío, entonces utiliza `expect(...).not_to be_empty`.

Comment: Ahora si, muchas gracias @Gerry